# How to set parameters for Festival TTS in C++

Tags: c++, linux, text-to-speech, festival

I am trying to develop a TTS program in linux, using festival. However, I can not find any api for parameters setting, such as rate and voice volume. Anyone have some idea?

Thanks,

Comment: I can't find any way to set rate, pitch or volume through the Scheme configuration files either :-(